# LaTeX table is outside the specified text area

Tags: tables, geometry

My thesis requires a specific sized text area of 150mm x 220mm which I have set using `\usepackage[a4paper, total={150mm, 220mm}]{geometry}` in my preamble and that seems to be working fine for the text, but not the tables. The tables are left aligned and they end up positioned further to the left than the text and are therefore outside of the specified text area. How do I go about rectifying this so that the tables remain left-aligned but within the text area?

The code that I use looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[a4paper, total={150mm, 220mm}]{geometry}


\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\usepackage{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\doublespacing}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-4]
\begingroup
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}[H]
\small
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}         
    \hline
          & \textbf{2 year} & \textbf{10 year} & \textbf{20 year} & \textbf{30 year} \\
         \hline\hline
         Canada & 0.123 & 0.549 & 0.641 & 0.671 \\
         Euro Area & 0.126 & 0.594 & 0.701 & 0.736 \\
         United Kingdom & 0.033 & 0.292 & 0.417 & 0.469 \\ [1ex]
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Theta Values}
    \label{tab:theta}
\end{table}
    \endgroup
\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: please provide an example that shows the issue. nothing in the code shown would change the left margin. what is in the group ended by the \endgroup ?

Comment: Why do you define 9 columns but your table only has 5 columns?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have added an image of what it looks like. Apologies, both of the questions that were raised were typos which I have now fixed.

Comment: Please post you code starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have edited the code in my post to include that now

Comment: That code is the whole preamble but I have obviously had to replace the text of my thesis with `\lipsum[2-4]`  in between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` but this now doesn't make the text into my required text area and I'm unsure why this has happened

Comment: With your posted code the table looks fine, inside the text area, So the problem is in the content you replaced with lipsum. Start by commenting out chapters until you found the culprit.

Comment: but \usepackage{fullpage}  will reset all the margins you set with geometry

Comment: Please post the image generated by the code posted. It is not useful to post an image generated by a different document. (The posted code only has one table not 6 which is flush to the left margin, a much smaller margin than you show in the image.)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to reduce font size in table form `\small` to `\footnotesize`. In this case is also recommended a wee bit adjust column specification to `{c >{$}X[c,m,wd=0.44\linewidth]<{$} *{3}{X[1,l,m]}},`.

[image]

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            total={150mm, 220mm},
            ]{geometry}  % <---
\usepackage{amssymb,
            mathtools}  % enhanced amsmath
% fonts
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
% tables
\usepackage{rotating}   % new
\usepackage{makecell}   % new
\usepackage{tabularray} % new
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
%\SetTblrInner{measure=box}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % new
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
    leftmargin=*,
    label=\textbullet,
    before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
    after ={\end{minipage}}
                  }
                            }% end of \AtBeginEnvironment

\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=footnotesize,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Summary of bottom-up parameterizations techniques used for polymer coarse-graining.}
\label{T:Summary}
    \footnotesize
\settowidth\rotheadsize{ Tomfoolery }   % from makecell
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {c >{$}
             X[c,m,wd=0.44\linewidth]<{$} % <---
             *{3}{X[1,l,m]}},  % <---
             colsep  = 3pt,
             rowsep  = 3pt,
             column{1}  = {cmd=\rotcell, font=\bfseries}, % <----
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
            }
    \cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    &   \text{Key Equation(s)}
        &   Key Inputs
            &   Advantages
                &   Dis\- advantages        \\
Relative Tomfoolery
    &   \begin{multlined}
    T_{\rm rel} = \beta \left\langle A_\text{GG} - B_\text{FF}\right\rangle_\text{FF} \\
                        -\beta(A_\text{GG} - A_\text{GG}) + \langle T_{\rm map} \rangle  _{AA}
        \end{multlined}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \ldots
        \item \ldots
            \end{itemize}
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item \ldots
            \item \ldots
                \end{itemize}
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item Sensitive optimization
                    \end{itemize}       \\
Integral Liquation Fine-Dinin
    &   \begin{aligned}
    \hat{a}_{ee}(k)
       & =  \frac{n_b^2 \hat{q}_{mm}(0) \bigl[\hat{\mu}_{bm}(k) \bigr]^2}
                  {1 + v_{m}\rho_{m} \hat{\lambda}_{mm}(0) \hat{\zeta}_{mm}(k)} \\
    \hat{\nu}_{bb}(k)
       &  = \frac{\hat{j}_{bb}(k)}
                  {n_{b} \hat{\zeta}_{bh}(k)
                    \bigl[n_{b} \hat{\omega}_{bb}(k) + \rho_{b} \hat{y}_{bb}(k) \bigr] }
        \end{aligned}
        &   \begin{itemize}
        \item \ldots
        \item \ldots
            \end{itemize}
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item \ldots
            \item \ldots
                \end{itemize}
                &   \begin{itemize}
            \item \ldots
            \item \ldots
                    \end{itemize}       \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```

All changes in in above MWE in comparison with yours are marked by `<---`.